# MariaDB Installation Hassles

Tags: package-management, permissions, dpkg, mariadb

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 after years of using Windows, most lately Win 10.

I’m mid-way through creating a repository for MariaDB according to [this procedure](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/Creating_a_Debian_Repository/)
f

The commands

**dpkg-scanpackages binary /dev/null | gzip -9c > binary/Packages.gz**

**dpkg-scansources source /dev/null | gzip -9c > source/Sources.gz**

evoke a response:

*Permission denied*

It makes no difference whether **sudo** is put before these commands or not.

Ideas welcome as having a repo in the apt directory will make it easier to update to newer versions of MariaDB.

At present, I’m doing the installing on my admin account and I was logged in on the appropriate password for admin while attempting making the repo.
I have a suspicion that a super-super user exists (called **root** and visible in the list of active processes) but I don’t know how to get at this account and its privileges.

If anyone has a means of removing a half-installed MariaDB installation and reinstalling it more efficiently, please advise.

## EDIT

Got into **root** account, established a password for it and removed the ~ 5GB of files put in just to install MariaDB . . . practically a whole distro of Debian.

In consideration of the fact that MariaDB is not doing much to make this process easy for its users - and expecting the usual dogfight over port 3306 - I've decided to leave it out for the time being.

Thanks to all responders.

Comment: If you're "just" going to install it, then why the need to create a repository?

Comment: Because the procedure says so. I reckon they want to have some where to update from but I'm not sure how things are done in Ubuntu.

Comment: Provided you have proper admin (sudo) rights, installing from the default repo should do the trick: `sudo apt install mariadb-server` followed by `sudo mysql_secure_installation`. [Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: If you need to clean up first, you might need to run: `sudo apt --purge remove "mysql*"` - or else search here for answers on how to remove incomplete installations.